# How to loop through MySQL results?

Tags: php, mysql

I done a query and have retrieved a set of MySQL results which I want to output in a table, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried. The PHP.net docs have a lot of simple examples.

Comment: Such information is available in a lot of other documentation. Please do some research before you ask such questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: see related on the right hand side there are many useful posts that can answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

If, for example you have a set of MySQL results you can loop through them using the `fetch_assoc()` method (providing you're using the MySQL Improved Extension).

For example:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("Your Query");

print("<table>");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td>" . $row['columnName'] . "</td>");
    print("</tr>");
}

print("</table>");
```